# Do jmeter random function will face bottle neck situation

Tags: json, jmeter

Let's say I have a random  function

```
           ${__Random(0,5)}
```

which I have mentioned in  multi JSON request, in a thread group with forever loop condition as:

```
    {
    Master= 
    {
    .. 
    ${__Random(0,10)}
    }
    {
    .. 
    ${__Random(0,10)}
    }
    {
    .. 
    ${__Random(0,10)}
    }
    {
    .. 
    ${__Random(0,10)}
    }
    {
    .. 
    ${__Random(0,10)}
     }
     }
```

Though the thread group is mentioned to run forever loop condition, do the thread keep running by duplicating the random variable or get stop aftr 10 iterations, since the max is 10.

my expectations is need to be keep running with duplications & the value need to be within specified range(0,10)..

Pls suggest/ calrify. TIA.

Comment: It will run forever by duplicating the random value. 
Just curious, why are you not checking it yourself by running and testing it out?

Comment: I was expecting this-- "Just curious, why are you not checking it yourself by running and testing it out?".. First i dont have Jmeter & it was for my fellow students. Before advising them i thought to get expertise views as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) chapter of the [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#best_practices)

> If your test needs large amounts of data - particularly if it needs to be randomised - create the test data in a file that can be read with CSV Dataset. This avoids wasting resources at run-time.

So a better idea would be pre-generating the request bodies somewhere in the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) and putting them into the .csv file. Then in the main Thread Group you can read the generated values via [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)